# How to get UGC posts of an organization in Linkedin v2 API

Tags: api, linkedin-api

In Linkedin v2 API, could not get the UGC posts of an organization managed by the user. But we can get the UGC posts of that user by following query.

```
curl "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?q=authors&oauth2_access_token=XXX"
```

Note: I have included `rw_organization` scope while authendication. Please someone help me resolve this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following url to get the 100 most recent posts on a company page:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?q=authors&authors=List(urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A{company_id})&count=100
```

where you need to replace the {company_id} with the relevant company id. Two headers must also be sent:

```
"Authorization": "Bearer {token}"
"X-Restli-Protocol-Version": "2.0.0"
```

where {token} is a token of a user who has admin rights for that company page. The LinkedIn API does not allow you to access company pages with a token from an account who lacks those rights.

Comment: ugcPosts endpoint only return the organic posts. Do you know how to set it to return even DARK posts of the respective page?